# How to do parsing in python?

Tags: python, database, parsing

I'm kinda new to Python. And I'm trying to find out how to do parsing in Python?
I've got a task: to do parsing with some piece of unknown for me symbols and put it to DB. I guess I can create DB and tables with help of SQLAlchemy, but I have no idea how to do parsing and what all these symbols below mean?

http://joxi.ru/YmEVXg6Iq3Q426

http://joxi.ru/E2pvG3NFxYgKrY

`$$HDRPUBID 112701130020011127162536 
H11127011300UNIQUEPONUMBER120011127

D11127011300UNIQUEPONUMBER100001112345678900000001

D21127011300UNIQUEPONUMBER1000011123456789AR000000001

D11127011300UNIQUEPONUMBER200002123456987X000000001

D21127011300UNIQUEPONUMBER200002123456987XIR000000000This item is inactive.                  9781605600000

$$EOFPUBID 1127011300200111271625360000005`

Thanks in advance those who can give me some advices what to start from and how the parsing is going on?

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRR9fOXkfRE

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to first figure out where each token begins and ends, and write a regular expression to capture these. The site [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) might help you design the regex.

Answer (score 0):

As other suggest take a look to some regex tutorials, and also [re module help](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). 
Probably you're looking to something like this:

```
import re
headerMapping = {'type': (1,5), 'pubid': (6,11), 'batchID': (12,21),
                 'batchDate': (22,29), 'batchTime': (30,35)}
poaBatchHeaders = re.findall('\$\$HDR\d{30}', text)
parsedBatchHeaders = []
batchHeaderDict = {}
for poaHeader in poaBatchHeaders:
    for key in headerMapping:
        start = headerMapping[key][0]-1
        end = headerMapping[key][1]
        batchHeaderDict.update({key: poaHeader[start:end]})
    parsedBatchHeaders.append(batchHeaderDict)
```

Then you have list with dicts, each dict contains data for each attribute. I assume that you have your datafile in `text` which is string. Each dict is made for one found structure (POA Batch Header in example).
If you want to parse it further, you have to made a function to parse each date in each attribute.

```
def batchDate(batch):
    return (batch[0:2]+'-'+batch[2:4]+'-20'+batch[4:])

for header in parsedBatchHeaders:
    header.update({'batchDate': batchDate( header['batchDate'] )})
```

Remember, that's an example and I don't know documentation of your data! I guess it works like that, but rest is up to you.